# NAS not recognizing hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, network-attached-storage, data-recovery

My work has a Thecus N89000 NAS with 5 hard drives, RAID 5. We had a power outage last week and when power returned the NAS was unable to find RAID and no network folders are found. In the admin console we’re only able to see 4 of the 5 drives. 1, 2, 4, 5.

Anyone have any ideas on what could of happened and how we can preserve our data? Should we attempt a fix or go right to file recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

this happens all the time, hard disk probably dead, you should remove this bad disk from NAS, power it on then, raid5 should work without one hard drive.. Ensure it is working, then install new disk instead of dead one and add to raid. When rebuild completes - you will have healthy storage.

Comment: Shouldn't RAID 5 be able to still function without one of the drives? Right now the NAS is saying no RAID found.